# Java Unit Testing: Mocking method that returns a boolean not working, getting NPE

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

This is a head-scratcher.  I have this:

```
@Autowired
KafkaConsumer kafkaConsumer;
...
private void ensureKafkaConsumerIsRunning() {
    if(!kafkaConsumer.isRunning()) {
        Thread kafkaThread = new Thread(kafkaConsumer);
        synchronized(KafkaConsumer.class) {
            kafkaThread.start();
        }
    }
}
```

The test:

```
@InjectMocks
private GreetingService greetingService;
...
@Mock
private KafkaConsumer kafkaConsumer;
...
@Test
public void sendToKafka_Msg_Test() throws Exception {
    RecordMetadata recordMetadata = new RecordMetadata(null, 0L,0L,0L,0L,0,0);
    when(kafkaConsumer.isRunning()).thenReturn(true);
    when(kafkaProducer.sync(anyString())).thenReturn(recordMetadata);
    assertEquals((long) greetingService.sendToKafka("test"), 0L);
}
```

I am getting a NPE in the class under test where it reads:

```
if(!kafkaConsumer.isRunning()) {
```

All isRunning() does is return a boolean 'isRunning' that is set either to true or false.  Nothing more.

I have tried making ensureKafkaConsumerIsRunning() public.  I have tried using Answers in the test instead of just when()s but to no avail.

Any ideas?

---

UPDATE:

It was so obvious it went right past us all!  Simply:

```
@Before
public void initMocks(){
     MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

Then that was that.  It worked.

Thank you to all who took the time to read and answer.

Comment: Your autowiring seems to fall on it's face. Check where the failure could be in there, preventing it to be autowired.

Comment: I agree: that is the thing when you bring multiple annotation based frameworks that do magic behind the covers. I guess something in your (test) setup is wrong. Probably that autowire overwrites what InjectMocks does ... anyway: try to reduce your problem to a [mcve] that you can share here.

Comment: Use a debugger to see what's going on there. Find out what's causing the NPE. Try rewriting your test using, i.e., `Mockito.mock()` method and the setter and see if it helps.

Comment: Is the class under test failing with a NPE or is the test failing with a NPE?

Answer (score 0):

It was so obvious it went right past us all! Simply:

```
@Before
public void initMocks(){
  MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

Then that was that. It worked.

Thank you to all who took the time to read and answer.

Comment: Btw, instead of this, you can also put `RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` onto your test class. Works the same way.

Answer (score -2):

Your `kafkaConsumer.isRunning()` is null if `isRunning` return `Boolean` and not `boolean` or `kafkaConsumer` is null.

Comment: Guessing is never an answer. This is a comment!

Comment: And I would be really really surprised if such a basic interface method on a well known framework says `Boolean isRunning()`. I would guess: these two annotations dont get along well, at least not in the way the OP has setup his test environment.

Comment: The NPE is throw because the kafkaConsumer object is null. A boolean return type method doesn't return null because it refuses to compile. That entire part of the answer before `kafkaConsumer is null` can be deleted.

Comment: You have to start your test with spring runner and change Mock to MockBean so your dependencies can be resolved properly. You can check here difference between mock and mockBean https://www.baeldung.com/java-spring-mockito-mock-mockbean .